# Comparison of enums values() method and class.getEnumConstants()

Tags: java, reflection, enums

I'm trying to compare this two ways to achieving the enums values (with and without reflection).

So this is my test class:

```
public class ReflectionOnEnumsTests2 {

    enum TestEnum { ONE, TWO, THREE; }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long n = 600_000_000;
        int stub;

        //test without Reflection
        long timeStartWithoutReflection = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
            TestEnum[] values = TestEnum.values();
            stub = values.length;
        }
        System.out.println("Time consuming with reflection: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - timeStartWithoutReflection));

        //test Reflection
        long timeStartWithReflection = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
            TestEnum[] values = TestEnum.class.getEnumConstants();
            stub = values.length;
        }
        System.out.println("Time consuming with reflection: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - timeStartWithReflection));
    }
}
```

And I'm confused about the test results. There is approximately the same time consuming. I expected that class.getEnumConstants would be much slower than values() method.

**Results:**

Time consuming with reflection: 6050

Time consuming with reflection: 7483

**JDK version:**
1.8.0_60

**Question:**

So why there is no difference in performance?

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: `Class` caches enum constants, therefore `getEnumConstants()` is pretty fast (for repeated calls)

Comment: @Jan why there is no difference in performance?

Comment: @bayou.io does this caching means that there is no reflective calls while iterations?

Comment: So if I want the array of enum constants, should I prefer `values()` or `class.getEnumConstants()` ?

Comment: It is interesting to note that JDK15/16 reports that the `values()` call as much faster (~20x) than `getEnumConstants()`.

Answer (score 3):

`TestEnum.class.getEnumConstants()` calls `values()` internally through reflection (at least in my version - Oracle's Java 7): take a look at `java.lang.Class.getEnumConstants()` and `java.lang.Class.getEnumConstantsShared()`

So it should only be slower by a reflection method lookup (probably constant time if a map is used) and by a clone of the result performed in `getEnumConstants()`.

Answer (score 3):

> So why there is no difference in performance?

Your own tests show the non-reflective approach being around 20% faster.  That may not be as much as you expected, but it's a non-trivial difference.

In fact, though, it's difficult to generalize your results in any way.  Performance-testing Java is tricky.  JIT compilation in particular can cause synthetic benchmarks such as yours to produce results that represent only themselves, and do not accurately characterize performance that can be expected in real application contexts.

In any event, you are proposing the wrong criterion for comparing these two approaches.  You should use the ordinary, non-reflective approach wherever you can *because it provides a better API*, even if the performance difference is only moderate.  The only reason *ever* to use reflection is that you cannot know enough until run time to determine the details of the action to take.  Such circumstances are rare.

Answer (score 1):

I am not surprised at those results.

When java loads an `enum`, a list of the values in the `Class` object, it will also create methods to access that list (namely `values()`).

When you use `TestEnum.values();` you will be given this list of values, and when you use `TestEnum.class.getEnumConstants();` all you are doing is getting the `Class` object and accessing the list directly.

Essentially, you are getting the same list, that is why there is no real time difference.