# Which usage is preferred Enum.values() or Enum.class.getEnumConstants()?

Tags: java, reflection, enums

To get the array of `enum` constants of some `Enum` type `TestEnum`, we have two options - `TestEnum.values()` or `TestEnum.class.getEnumConstants()`. When I looked at the code, I could see that the `getEnumConstants()` is invoking the `values()` method through reflection and then caching it for future usage. Before returning, the array is cloned as well.

From the below question and its answers (which focuses only on performance), it seems that there aren't much difference in performance.

[Comparison of enums values() method and class.getEnumConstants()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32907575/comparison-of-enums-values-method-and-class-getenumconstants#comment116979240_32907575)

I would like to know whether one of these methods is preferred over the other. One scenario which I could think of is when creating a method which works on generics where we pass a generic `enum` class as the argument.

```java
<E extends Enum<E>> void doSomething(Class<E> clazz){
    for(E type : clazz.getEnumConstants()){
        // do something...
    }
}
```

In the above case, we could only use the `getEnumConstants` approach.

Are there any other similar scenarios? If I am sure about the type of the `enum` which I am going to use, then isn't it better to use `values()` approach?

Comment: Use `values()` unless you need to use reflection.

Comment: @Slaw Any possible scenarios where reflection is to be used? other than the one I have mentioned

Comment: The simple answer is that you only need `getEnumConstants()` when the type is only known at runtime. If you have static access to the class at compile-time, there's no reason not to use `values()`.

Comment: @ernest_k I suggest you make an Amswer of that Comment, so this page can be resolved.

Comment: Thanks for the positive influence :), @BasilBourque

Comment: @Gautham M The question you mentioned prints test results from JDK1.8, but if you run it on JDK16 the output has hugely different timing results in favour of values().

Comment: @DuncG Are there any reference pages to get more details on this?

Comment: JDK16 source code shows that `getEnumConstants()` calls `values()` via reflection and caches the array for clone.  Use `values()` where possible as @ernest_k / @Slaw suggest.

Comment: @DuncG It is the same in JDK 8 as well. They get the values from cache or via reflection(if not in cache), cache the values if fetched via reflection and clone it before returning. I don't see any significant changes in the source code between JDK 8 to JDK 16. Infact the logic was the same from JDK 1.5 itself !! (only very few minor cleanup was done in the method in future releases)

Comment: @Gautham M JDK optimisations clearly make a difference - timings of that example on my PC show JDK16 `values()` call appears 10x quicker than JDK1.8, whereas the JDK1.8 `getEnumConstants()` appears to be a bit quicker than in JDK16.

Comment: @DuncG I am not sure about the JDK optimizations, but what I intended was that a source code change was not introduced as part of JDK16.

 "JDK16 source code shows that getEnumConstants() calls values() via reflection and caches the array for clone." - for some users, reading this comment might make them think that the a source code change was introduced as part of JDK16.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only answer applicable here is based on what each of these options was designed for.

Methods available on the `Class` class are designed for dynamic, runtime inspection of classes, so `Class.getEnumConstants()` is to be used when the enum class to list values for is only known when the program is running. Your example of lookup in a generic method illustrates the correct use.

If you know the class statically, then you should use `YourEnumClass.values()`. There is no valid reason to go through a `Class` instance to do that.

Comment: Updated the question with code for the generic method example